# "Polygons and gravitons" and Kodaira's theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand the paper by Hitchin called: [''Polygons and gravitons"](http://inspirehep.net/record/151308). I'm stuck at page 470. At this point, he does some computations and obtains the conformal structure of the real manifold.

I know that because of Kodaria's theorem, there exist a 4-dimensional complex manifold that parametrizes the sections of $H^k\oplus H^k\oplus H^2$. Furthermore, because of this theorem, there is an isomorphism between the sections of the normal bundle and the tangent vectors of the 4-dimensional manifold. Using the notation of the article, a point $(a,b,c,A)$ of the manifold corresponds to a section of $H^k\oplus H^k\oplus H^2$, i.e. to certain $x(u),y(u),z(u)$. However, I don't understand how to see the relation between a tangent vector $(a',b',c',A')$ on the point $(a,b,c,A)$ and a section $(x',y',z')\in ker(f_x,f_y,f_z)$.

Actually, I also don't know how to interpret this section $(x',y',z')$. Is it a section of $H \oplus H$ ?

I can follow the computations done at this point but I don't see this equality:
$$Re\left(\frac{2A'}{A} \right)=\sum \frac{(b-b_i)'+\Delta_i'}{(b-b_i)+\Delta_i}=\gamma b'+Re(\delta a')$$
Any help will be very welcome. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest that you make this question more self-contained by explaining the definitions and the context.  The process of doing this may well help you to understand what is going on,  as well as increasing the probability that you will get an answer from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The computations are these:
Let us see this equality. 
$$\ln\left(A\bar{A}\right)=\ln A+\ln \bar{A}=2\text{Re}\ln A =\ln\left(\prod \left((b-b_i)-\Delta_i \right)\right)=\sum \ln\left((b-b_i)-\Delta_i \right)\Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow (2\text{Re}\ln A)'=2Re\left(\dfrac{A'}{A}\right)=Re\left(\dfrac{2A'}{A}\right)=\sum \dfrac{(b-b_i)'+\Delta_i'}{(b-b_i)+\Delta_i}$$
On the other hand, 
$$\dfrac{|a-a_i|'}{|a-a_i|}=(\ln|a-a_i|)'=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left((a-a_i)(\bar{a}-\bar{a}_i)\right)'=\dfrac{1}{2}\left( 2\text{Re}\ln (a-a_i) \right)'=\text{Re}\left( \dfrac{a'}{a-a_i}\right)$$
Hence, using that $\alpha_i=\frac{-(b-b_i)+\Delta_i}{a-a_i}$
$$\text{Re}(\delta a')=\sum \text{Re}\left(\dfrac{a'}{a-a_i}\dfrac{\Delta_i-(b-b_i)}{\Delta_i} \right)=\sum \text{Re}\left(\dfrac{a'}{a-a_i}\right)\dfrac{\Delta_i-(b-b_i)}{\Delta_i}\Rightarrow $$$$\Rightarrow \text{Re}(\delta a') = \sum\dfrac{|a-a_i|'}{|a-a_i|}\dfrac{\Delta_i-(b-b_i)}{\Delta_i}$$
and therefore we finally obtain:
$$\text{Re}(\delta a')+\gamma b'=\sum\left( \dfrac{|a-a_i|'}{|a-a_i|}\dfrac{\Delta_i-(b-b_i)}{\Delta_i}+\dfrac{b'}{\Delta_i}\right)=$$$$=\sum \left(\dfrac{\dfrac{|a-a_i|'}{|a-a_i|}\left(\Delta_i-\Delta_i^{-1}(b-b_i)^2\right)+b'+\Delta_i^{-1}(b-b_i)b'}{(b-b_i)+\Delta_i} \right)=$$$$=\sum \left(\dfrac{\dfrac{|a-a_i|'}{|a-a_i|}\dfrac{|a-a_i|^2}{\Delta_i}+b'+\dfrac{(b-b_i)b'}{\Delta_i}}{(b-b_i)+\Delta_i} \right)= $$$$=\sum \left(\dfrac{\dfrac{|a-a_i||a-a_i|'+(b-b_i)b'}{\Delta_i}+b'}{(b-b_i)+\Delta_i} \right)=\sum\frac{(b-b_i)'+\Delta_i'}{(b-b_i)+\Delta_i}$$